# Ruby 1.9.1 and Aptana Studio 3 Cant get debug to work (Windows)

Tags: ruby, aptana, ruby-debug, ruby-1.9.1

So for the last few weeks ive been reading posts on SO and other sites about Ruby IDE's, especially for support with Ruby 1.9. Aptana/RadRails plugin looks amazing as im very used to the eclipse environment, so I thought id give it a try.

I installed ruby 1.9.1 with ruby installer and also installed devKit and Aptana studio 3. However I cant debug in Aptana as I get the following error:

```
c:/Ruby191/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:323:in `bin_path': can't find gem ruby-debug-ide ([">= 0"]) (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
    from <internal:gem_prelude>:346:in `method_missing'
    from c:/Ruby191/bin/rdebug-ide:19:in `<main>'
```

So i tried to do a `gem install ruby-debug-ide` and get the following:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing ruby-debug-ide:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

c:/Ruby191/bin/ruby.exe mkrf_conf.rb
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...


Gem files will remain installed in c:/Ruby191/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.16 for inspection.
Results logged to c:/Ruby191/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.16/ext/gem_make.out
```

It appears to be ridiculously difficult to get a decent IDE with ruby 1.9 support with a functioning debugger - I am clearly doing it wrong, any help would be appreciated.

-----EDIT-----

Output of c:/Ruby191/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.16/ext/gem_make.out below

```
C:/Ruby191/bin/ruby.exe mkrf_conf.rb
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
```

Aly

Answer (score 1):

What are the contents of `gem_make.out` mentioned in the output?

For Ruby 1.9.x, you need `ruby-debug-ide19`, since it works with 1.9.x versions of Ruby.

Also, you need a compiler. If you're using RubyInstaller releases, you need to obtain RubyInstaller Development Kit, listed in the [downloads](http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads) page

Please read the text in that page and the [Development Kit instructions](http://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit) in our wiki.

EDIT: Based on the lack of content of your gem_make.out file (since it shouldn't say anything about building extensions) I would recommend you look at [RubyInstaller Troubleshooting](https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Troubleshooting) page in our wiki.

Comment: I already have DevKit installed, and tried doing gem install ruby-debug-ide19 and go the same error I have edited the question to add the contents of gem_make.out

Comment: Seem my updated response, your gem_make.out do not contain anything like it normally would, which could indicate something is not right in your environment. Are you trying to install from the console? Did DevKit installed properly? Can you verify the Troubleshooting page and post something to RubyInstaller group in case nothing there is in your environment?

Comment: Also, please paste the output of gem_make.out of ruby-debug-ide19 and ruby-debug19 since that is the correct version for your installation of Ruby

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue: could not debug, and also could not run a file with a require of a file in the folder.

I rolled back by Ruby installation to 1.87, and all is working.

Apologies in advance if you really need 1.9x.

Answer (score 0):

I also had these build issues when using ruby 1.9.3.See my answer here :
[Ruby-debug not working - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9260206/889617)

It's about getting Ruby debugging to work with the following setup

- Mac OS X Lion 10.7.2
- Aptana Studio 3 (Build 3.0.8.201201201658)
- Using rvm, in my project working directory I have a .rvmrc stating:

  ```
  rvm use ruby-1.9.3-p0@mygemset
  ```

I hope this helps!

-- Freddy

Answer (score 0):

One thing you might want to do is include the path to your "**rdebug-ide**" file (this is a file without an extension) in your Path env variable. Although this might be a hack, it worked for me. 
Mine was located at:
**C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby2.0.0\lib\ruby\gems\2.0.0\gems\ruby-debug-ide-0.4.22\bin**

It may be in a different location if you didn't use RailsInstaller.

You also need to ensure that your **GEM_HOME** variable is pointing to the proper location.

Hope this helps!