# Is ruby-debug-ide available to be installed on windows with ruby1.9.3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-debug

I was trying to install ruby-debug-ide on my windows ruby environment. A lot of errors show up. My environment are Ruby1.9.3, Windows 7 and DevKit. So is there any guide to install ruby-debug-ide which can be used on the Aptana Studio.

Answer (score 4):

I had lots of problems with this too, which I was able to solve after a lot of Googling.

Install rubyinstaller-1.9.3-p327.exe

Extract DevKit-tdm-32-4.5.2-20111229-1559-sfx.exe to somewhere

cd to where it is (where you find dk.rb)

run: ruby dk.rb init

```
 ruby dk.rb install
```

Go to http://rubyforge.org/frs/?group_id=8883 to download the gems below

cd to where the *.gem files are

`gem uninstall ruby-debug-ide ruby-debug-base linecache`

`gem install linecache19-0.5.13.gem`

`gem install ruby-debug-base19-0.11.26.gem -- --with-ruby-include=C:\Ruby193\include\ruby-1.9.1\ruby-1.9.3-p327`

`gem install ruby-debug-ide19-0.4.12.gem`

After all this you might still face the problem with is_binary_data? which was resolved in another thread. Thanks to all the great help. I'm not sure why all this are not packed in rubyinstaller itself though. After all, debugging should be a minimum.

Comment: Paul's solution is perfect, but it worths mentioning that one has to change ruby-1.9.3-p327 with its ruby's build. I had to replace > gem install ruby-debug-base19-0.11.26.gem --
> --with-ruby-include=C:\Ruby193\include\ruby-1.9.1\ruby-1.9.3-p327 with > gem install ruby-debug-base19-0.11.26.gem --
> --with-ruby-include=C:\Ruby193\include\ruby-1.9.1\ruby-1.9.3-p194

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the version of `ruby-debug19` gem available at rubygems.org is not up-to-date.

Instead, for some strange reason, gem author only pushed the gems to RubyForge:

http://rubyforge.org/projects/ruby-debug19

See the announcement here:

http://rubyforge.org/forum/forum.php?forum_id=39580

I've tried poking the gem author without success.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I have install the ruby-debug19 gem file from the website you gave me. But it still can't work on the AptanaStudio. When I try to debug a Ruby program, I get some error like this: Exception in DebugThread loop: undefined method `is_binary_data?' for "#<Account:0x23c35e0>":String

Comment: That is another issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8961367/aptana-3-ruby-debugger-exception-in-debugthread-loop-undefined-method-is-bin/9043481#9043481