# Windows 8 64 bit ruby-debug-ide install of linecache19 failing due to gcc -m64 flag error: sorry, unimplemented: 64-bit mode not compiled in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, c, ruby, gcc, windows-8

I am going through the install for windows per [Is ruby-debug-ide available to be installed on windows with ruby1.9.3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9408670/is-ruby-debug-ide-available-to-be-installed-on-windows-with-ruby1-9-3) downloaded the gems and begin to install them. But get this 64 bit error. Is there a 32 bit version of linecache19. Do I need a different gcc compiler?

```
C:\JRuby\lib\ruby\gems\shared>gem install linecache19-0.5.13.gem
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing linecache19-0.5.13.gem:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        C:/JRuby/bin/jruby.exe extconf.rb
C:/JRuby/lib/ruby/shared/mkmf.rb:14: Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.
checking for vm_core.h... no
checking for vm_core.h... yes
checking for version.h... yes
creating Makefile

make
gcc -I. -IC:/JRuby/lib/native/include -IC:/JRuby/lib/native/include/ruby -I. -DHAVE_VM_CORE_H -DHAVE_VERSION_H -IC:/JRuby/lib/native/include
/ruby-1.9.3-p392 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing  -fexceptions    -m64 -march=native -mtune=native -c trace_nums.c
trace_nums.c:1:0: sorry, unimplemented: 64-bit mode not compiled in
```

Comment: Do you have a 64-bit `gcc` installed?

Comment: I grabbed a http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/ toolchain targeting Win 64 and installed. set path=C:\Utils\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\bin;%path% set path=C:\Utils\mingw64\libexec\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.7.0;%path% copy stdint.h and _mingw.h from C:\Utils\mingw64\mingw\include to C:\JRuby\lib\native\include\ruby and then downloaded ruby source code from http://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/1.9/ now I am back to original error checking for vm_core.h... no

Comment: Are you sure your 32-bit compiler isn't first in your path?

Comment: Huh. What version of JRuby do you use? Since you are on windows i'd suggest you to use ruby 2.0 32-bit from [rubyinstaller](http://rubyinstaller.org/). You may also try jruby variations of debugger gems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you've tried to install a gem (linecache19) on top of JRuby.

JRuby is powered by JVM, and installation of gems that pack C extensions is discourages (due performance issues)

If you plan to continue using JRuby and you're interested in things like debugging and such, I recommend you read JRuby documentation about [how to debug with JRuby](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/UsingTheJRubyDebugger)

If you're still interested in install linecache19 (and debugger gem), I recommend you install a version of Ruby that is compatible with C extension compilation, like RubyInstaller:

http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads

As mentioned in the download page, if you're new to Ruby/Rails world, I suggest you use Ruby 1.9.3 instead of Ruby 2.0 since not all the gems have been updated to be compatible with 2.0 on Windows.

Hope that helps.