# ruby-debug not finding variables in rspec (in sinatra)

Tags: ruby, rspec, sinatra, ruby-debug

In my `Gemfile` I have (as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/8351945/111884)

```
gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'
```

In my `spec_helper.rb` I have

```
require 'ruby-debug'
```

But when I put in `debugger` in my spec files, I can't seem to access any variables. I get errors like:

```
(rdb:1) @project
*** Unknown command: "@project".  Try "help".
```

I've had it work on another computer before, but I can't check on that at the moment. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to type:

```
(rdb:1) p @project
```

Debugger is not irb, it works with commands. So you should type command first. `p` means print, then type what you want to print.
To see full list of commands, just type `help`.

Comment: I also found that if you run `irb` in the debugger console, you can get an irb console