# Aptana 3 and ruby debugging

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, aptana3, ruby-debug

How I can set the watch on variable's in ruby. I am using Aptana as IDE. I am coming for .NET and am used to seeing the variable values just by hovering over the variable.

In aptana 3 i cant find way through which i see current state and values of the variable. I seeing the self object there too much information and difficut to find the value of the variable i am looking for  ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8351604/ruby-debug-not-working/9260206#9260206) to a very similar question includes step-by-step instructions on getting ruby-debug-ide to work with Aptana 3. It's written from an OS X perspective but you should be able to apply it to your own setup readily (take special care to read the RVM/not-RVM notes).

Comment: Debugger is working fine only watch for variable is not working. The post which you are referring to shows how to install debugger if it is not working at all

Comment: I don't use Aptana so this is beyond the scope of my expertise. Not to be glib, but if I were you I'd just use the debugger CLI—it's very capable.