# How disable automatic logging in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using logger to log the values of the variables for debuging. Because automatic debugging logs it is diffcult to find values

How to slient automatic logging?

Comment: Have you considered using an actual debugger, such as the one described very thoroughly in the [Debugging Rails Applications](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html) Rails Guide? Like most debuggers it lets you pause execution wherever you want or watch the value of any variable.

Comment: I am facing chanllenges with watch http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10730578/aptana-3-and-ruby-debugging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure Rails logger in `config/application.rb`. `config.log_level` defines the verbosity of the Rails logger.  The available log levels are: `:debug, :info, :warn, :error, :fatal`.

Example:

```
config.log_level = :warn
```

Also read information about Logger:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#the-logger

Answer (score 2):

You can't turn if off completely while still having *your* log messages go to the log, but there are a couple of solutions I can think of:

1. Set logging to a very high level (like `:fatal`), then log your messages at that level. There shouldn't be much noise in the log at that log level.
2. Prefix your log messages with a unique identifier, e.g. `MYSTUFF`, then grep for that when you're tailing the log: `tail -f log/production.log | grep MYSTUFF`. Doing it this way means you don't have to change your log configuration.